# XML feed google shopping

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

We already have a working XML that we make available on a link for Google Merchant Center to use (for a webshop in gardening products). In short it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <title>Companyname product data feed</title>
    <link rel="self" href="http://igarden.nl"/>
    <updated>2014-07-08 08:23:18</updated>
    <author>
        <name>Our companyname</name>
    </author><id>tag:companyname.nl,2014-07-08</id>
    <entry>
        <id>1001</id>
        <title>Productname</title>
        <link href="http://companyname.nl/"/>
        <g:price>123,10</g:price>
        <description>omschrijving van het product</description>
        <g:condition>new</g:condition>
        <g:brand>acd</g:brand>
        <g:mpn>12321</g:mpn>
        <g:ean>21353532235</g:ean>
        <g:image_link>http://companyname.nl/images/imagename.png</g:image_link>
        <g:product_type>Huis &amp; Tuin &gt; category</g:product_type>
        <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
        <g:shipping>
            <g:country>NL</g:country>
            <g:service>Standaard</g:service>
            <g:price>6,50</g:price>
        </g:shipping>
        <g:manufacturer>acd2</g:manufacturer>
        <g:weight>100g</g:weight>
        <g:featured_product>0</g:featured_product>
        <g:size>20x20x20</g:size>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

We're remaking the webshop, so I wanted to try to make it with DOMDocument, but I find it difficult. This is what I have so far in code:

```
/* create a dom document with encoding utf8 */
$domtree = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

/* create the root element of the xml tree */
$xmlRoot = $domtree->createElement("feed");
$xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild($xmlRoot);

$addProduct = $domtree->createElement("entry");
$addProduct = $xmlRoot->appendChild($addProduct);
$addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElement('id','100123'));
$addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElement('title','Blokhut'));
$addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElement('g:price','123,50'));
$addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElement('description','omschrijving van de blokhut'));
$addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElement('g:condition','new'));

/* get the xml printed */
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
$domtree->formatOutput = true;
echo $domtree->saveXML();
```

Which outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed>
  <entry>
    <id>100123</id>
    <title>Blokhut</title>
    <g:price>123,50</g:price>
    <description>omschrijving van de blokhut</description>
    <g:condition>new</g:condition>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

So I got the basics working, but I have no clue how to make some elements working. How do I make these rows:

- Add this part to `<feed>`: `<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">`
- `<title>Compayname product data feed</title>`
- `<link href="http://companyname.nl/"/>`
- The `<g:shipping>` sub part

If I know how to make these, I think I can fill in the rest of the XML. I've tried so many things I found on here and by Googling, but I can't get them to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML uses namespaces, so you have to use `createElementNS()` not `createElement()`

```
$xmlns = [
  'atom' => 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom',
  'g' =>'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0'
];

$xmlRoot = $domtree->appendChild(
  $domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['atom'], 'feed')
);
...
$addProduct->appendChild($domtree->createElementNS($xmlns['g'], 'g:price','123,50'));
```

The namespace definitions (xmlns attributes) are added automatically. To force that for a specific node, you can add a dummy attribute:

```
$xmlRoot->setAttributeNS($xmlns['g'], 'g:dummy', '');
$xmlRoot->removeAttribute('g:dummy');
```

Demo: https://eval.in/170402

Comment: Thanks that works! But I still don't know how to do these two things: `<link href="http://companyname.nl/"/>` and the `<g:shipping>` part. Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: Same rules, `link` is in the atom namespace, `g:shipping` in the google namespace. `g:shipping` has child elements, so you have to append them to the `g:shipping` element, not the `entry` element.

Comment: I'm beginning to understand the principle, but I can't seem to get them to work. Whatever I try, it just doesn't seem to work. That's why I asked for a code example :-)

Comment: You use createElementNS() to create an element node (with namespace), setAttribute() to add attributes to it, appendChild() to a child node to its parent element node.

Comment: I got the g:shipping and link part working now, by googling some more.